# Vertical align an image in div

Tags: html, css, image

I have a div container with a fixed height. The image in the div can be lager than de height of the div. The width of the image is set to 100% of the div. I would like to the image to be vertically centered; now the top of the image is shown, which sometimes can create a strange looking crop.

The html is:

```
<div class="itemImageBlock" style="/* padding:0px; */">
      <span>
        <a class="modal" rel="{handler: 'image'}" href="/media/k2/items/cache/23ac69ecf90d97d87602b5da326dea8e_XL.jpg" title="Klik om afbeelding te bekijken">
            <figure>
                <img src="/media/k2/items/cache/23ac69ecf90d97d87602b5da326dea8e_L.jpg" alt="Bootleg Betty" style="width:100%; height:auto;">
            </figure>
        </a>
      </span>

  </div>
```

And the css is:

```
div.itemImageBlock {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 0 16px 0;
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've tried to use display: table-cell; but then I loose the height and get a full image. (that is the overflow: hidden is lost)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it using the CSS3 transform function `translate` and some absolute positioning.

On the parent container, set the height value and `position: relative`.

The child container `span` is then absolutely positioned with the top at 50%
from the top edge of the parent.

You can then use `transform: translateY(-50%)` to move the span/image to the center of the parent block.

Using `overflow: hidden` hides the top and bottom portion of the image.

If the image height is short enough, the top/bottom space takes on the background color (or image) as the case may be.

```css
div.itemImageBlock {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.itemImageBlock span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%)
}
div.itemImageBlock img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
figure {  /* Optional reset */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemImageBlock"> 
    <span>
        <a href="">
            <figure>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/500x800" >
            </figure>
        </a>
      </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.yourClass {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[You can read about this more here.](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments, this method must be applied to a `div` not a `span`, so either replace the span with a div, or wrap it in a div.

Comment: This is wrong (check here http://jsfiddle.net/av7j761p/). Shouldn't you use position absolute, and relative in the parent?

Comment: If the height of the parent is known and fixed, then yes absolute would be better. but the reason your JSFiddle isn't working is because it doesn't work on a span element. You have to use a block element like a div.

Comment: Heres is an update where i changed the span to a div http://jsfiddle.net/av7j761p/1/

Comment: I changed only the top one to show you. The other two are still spans

Comment: indeed, but the OP uses a span. i think you should include the new html if you do it like this